# Multiple default folders

Tags: downloads

[image]

The folders like Documents, Downloads, etc. are repeated twice. Top ones are not able to open and bottom ones open. When I open the top right it shows

```
Unhandled error message: Error when getting information for file '/home/stanly/DOWNLOAD': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Post these: `cat /etc/fstab`; `mount`; `lsblk -o NAME,LABEL,SIZE,UUID,MOUNTPOINT`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23611638/

Comment: That is not showing any mounts at all?  We used to see external drives with mounts in fstab and then mounted with Nautilus shown twice, but only one mount would work. Are you linking or something else that makes a second mount?